# Passing object attributes to its methods (Python)

Tags: python, class, methods, attributes

It is apparently impossible to pass attributes of an object to its own methods:

```
def drawBox(color):
    print("A new box of color ", color)
    return

class Box:
    def __init__(self, color):
        self.defaultColor = color
        self.color = color

    def update(self, color = self.defaultColor):
        self.color = color
        drawBox(color)
```

This does not work:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 5, in <module> 
File "<string>", line 9, in Box 
NameError: name 'self' is not defined
```

I found a way to bypass this issue like this:

```
def drawBox(color):
    print("A new box of color ", color)
    return

class Box:
    def __init__(self, color):
        self.defaultColor = color
        self.color = color
    def update(self, color = None):
        if color == None:
            self.color = self.defaultColor
        else:
            self.color = color
        drawBox(color)
```

Is there a better (more elegant?) way to do this?

Comment: "It is apparently impossible to pass attributes of an object to its own methods:" that just doesn't make sense. You don't *pass attributes*. You *pass objects*. It is perfectly possible to pass an object using an attribute reference. The problem is that `self` is not defined in the class body -- of course not, `self` is simply *the conventional name given to the first paramter of a method*, it won't be defined *until you call the method*

Comment: in any case, your solution is fine. Maybe use `if color is None: ...` to be more idiomatic

Comment: Note, `def update(self, color = self.defaultColor):` is *not passing anything*, that is part of a *function definition*. There is no "passing" involved because it isn't a *function call*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason you can't use `self.color` as a default parameter value is that the default is evaluated at the time the method is defined (*not* at the time that it's called), and at the time the method is defined, there is no `self` object yet.

Assuming that a valid `color` is always a truthy value, I would write this as:

```
class Box:
    def __init__(self, color):
        self.default_color = self.color = color

    def draw(self):
        print(f"A new box of color {self.color}")

    def update(self, color=None):
        self.color = color or self.default_color
        self.draw()
```

Comment: I mean, this really isn't more "elegant" that the pretty canonical solution the OP already found

Comment: In the eye of the beholder, I guess, but I really love Python's `or` operator for being able to turn a very common `if/else` pattern into a graceful one-liner.